# Custom buttons in exoplayer

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, exoplayer

I'd like to add more buttons to my exoplayer layout. How can I add an onClicklistener to my custom button in the layout so that when I click on it changes can take affect in my player activity?

I'm using kotlin and databinding. Also this is my first app that I'm trying to make so I haven't much knowledge.

Comment: Paste your existing layout where you want to add additional buttons.

Comment: I've moved on. It's not possible to control the exoplayer layout with view binding if you're adding custom buttons. Used findViewById() instead

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your button has an ID `newButton`, and the binding object is called `mBinding`, then you can set up the listener as follow:

```
mBinding.newButton.setOnClickListener { onDoSomething() }
```

This can either be inside the `onCreate()` for an activity and `onViewCreated()` for a fragment.
`onDoSomething()` is where the application logic goes.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override **controller_layout_id** with your custom layout
like below (the quoted line)

```
 <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
    android:id="@+id/exoplayer_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
```

> ```
>     app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_layout"
> ```

```
    app:fastforward_increment="10000"
    app:hide_on_touch="true"
    app:player_layout_id="@layout/exo_player_view"
    app:resize_mode="fit"
    app:rewind_increment="10000"
    app:show_timeout="4000"
    app:shutter_background_color="#000000"
    app:surface_type="surface_view"
    app:use_controller="true" />
```

Your custom layout should be something like this (the image below)

[Custom layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r63Gk.jpg)

Don't forget to use corresponding ID's for each Icon

```
  <drawable name="exo_controls_play">@drawable/exo_icon_play</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_pause">@drawable/exo_icon_pause</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_next">@drawable/exo_icon_next</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_previous">@drawable/exo_icon_previous</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_fastforward">@drawable/exo_icon_fastforward</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_rewind">@drawable/exo_icon_rewind</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_repeat_all">@drawable/exo_icon_repeat_all</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_repeat_off">@drawable/exo_icon_repeat_off</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_repeat_one">@drawable/exo_icon_repeat_one</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_shuffle_off">@drawable/exo_icon_shuffle_off</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_shuffle_on">@drawable/exo_icon_shuffle_on</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_fullscreen_enter">@drawable/exo_icon_fullscreen_enter</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_fullscreen_exit">@drawable/exo_icon_fullscreen_exit</drawable>
  <drawable name="exo_controls_vr">@drawable/exo_icon_vr</drawable>
```